# Mostrar / Ocultar o console em uma aplicação em c#

Tags: c#, console

Procurei sobre como mostrar/ocultar o console em uma aplicação em c# nos fóruns em português e não encontrei. Procurando nos internacionais me deparei com várias soluções porém encontrei uma de muito fácil aplicação e gostaria de compartilhar com os demais.

**Como ocultar (e mostrar) a janela do console associada com sua própria aplicação console?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue o código:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

const int SW_HIDE = 0;
const int SW_SHOW = 5;
var handle = GetConsoleWindow();

// Ocultar
ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);

// Mostrar
ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW);
```